# Why my DataGridView show blank rows with datasource being BindingList<>?

Tags: c#

After binding the datasource, the rows would grow after click. but the all rows are blank. How could I solve this ?

```
 BindingList<Info> infos = new BindingList<Info>();

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.DataSource = infos;
            infos.Add(new Info("asadasdasds", "asasdafasdfed"));
        }

 class Info
    {
        public string a = "";
        public string b = "";
        public Info(string aa, string bb)
        {
            a = aa;b = bb;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ar you auto-generating the columns? Does the `Info` class have any public properties?

Comment: If `Info` has no properties, nothing will show

Comment: yep, public properties.

Comment: found the problem. after change it to properties.it works